# Lock x axis rotation when using OrbitControls - Three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js

Is it feasible to lock the x axis rotation when using OrbitControls? Currently I have an object model of a christmas star hung on a string. I want it to rotate only horizontally.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

For your OrbitControls instance set

```
controls.minPolarAngle = Math.PI/2;
controls.maxPolarAngle = Math.PI/2;
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thanks.

Comment: @prisoner849 could you provide an explanation here? what if I want to block a different axis ?

Comment: @NeelanshVerma change camera's `.up` vector.