# THREE.JS - Lock y axis rotation when using OrbitControls

Tags: javascript, three.js

I have a three.js scene and im using OrbitControls to rotate the camera around the origin position of `0,0,0`

I'm trying to lock the camera to be able to rotate infinitely on on the y-axis (vertically going up or down)

You can see the scene im working on here:
https://www.fariskassim.com/stage/rebel9/gyeonggicheon/carousel/v1/index.html

I've tried the following but its doesnt really rotate whole way round and its not infinite either

```
  controls.minAzimuthAngle = 0;
  controls.maxAzimuthAngle = 0;
```

There's a similar question here that locks the camera on the x-axis, but im not sure how to change it to lock on y only
[Lock x axis rotation when using OrbitControls - Three.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41135592/lock-x-axis-rotation-when-using-orbitcontrols-three-js)

Answer (score -1):

use

```
controls.minPolarAngle=controls.maxPolarAngle=1.57079
```

Comment: Did you just copy the answer from the linked question? You could have atleast explained where you got this seemingly random number from. (yes I know it is Math.PI/2).

Comment: You will also see the example linked to is now working with `controls.minAzimuthAngle = Math.PI; controls.maxAzimuthAngle = Math.PI;`

Comment: Thanks. I wanted the vertical axis locked and this worked!